# Figurative meaning of 'downstream'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [[30% down the page]](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/racism-still-an-uncomfortable-truth-in-canada-duncan-mccue-1.2831066) This split-second eye bias can have some important consequences, according to [[Prof.] Kawakami](http://www.kawakamilab.org/lab-members/). When we don’t make eye contact with someone, we’re less likely to be able to decode their emotions, and less willing to trust or remember that person.
>
> "Even though it might happen within the first 100th of a second, we know that **downstream** that can tell us whether you might hire a person, whether you have positive or negative associations with that person and whether you’re willing to interact with that person," Kawakami explained.

Which definition, if any, applies,from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downstream or http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/downstream?

Comment: The M-W page is replete with ads and only has two definitions. I think it would be much better if you copy-and-pasted the definitions into the question, rather than provide a link that forces everyone who is interested in answering your question go visit two sites. Please fix this, and follow this guidance in future questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this definition of [downstream](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/downstream) sense 2:

> 2) at or toward the end of some process, course of activity, etc.

In your examples, it would be courses of activity with some later conclusion, such as whether or not you hire someone, associate with someone, or interact with someone.